# Creating calculated field with subquery in oracle

Tags: oracle, subquery, calculated-columns

so I'm new to Oracle SQL and am trying to create a calculated column using a subquery. It seems like this information shouldn't be so hard to find but I haven't been able to find it... I would really appreciate any guidance!

```
SQL> CREATE VIEW booking_agent_view
  2  AS
  3  SELECT sf.flight_nbr, sf.flight_date, seats_available,
  4  FROM sched_flight sf, aircraft_type at, aircraft_data ad, (SELECT count(cust_nbr) FROM reservation r GROUP BY flight_nbr, flight_date) seats_available
  5  WHERE sf.aircraft_serial_nbr = at.aircraft_serial_nbr AND at.type=ad.type;

FROM sched_flight sf, aircraft_type at, aircraft_data ad, (SELECT count(cust_nbr) FROM reservation r GROUP BY flight_nbr, flight_date) AS seats_available
*
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00936: missing expression
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW booking_agent_view
AS
SELECT sf.flight_nbr, 
       sf.flight_date, 
       --
      (SELECT count(cust_nbr) 
       FROM reservation r 
      ) seats_available
FROM sched_flight sf, 
     aircraft_type at, 
     aircraft_data ad    
WHERE sf.aircraft_serial_nbr = at.aircraft_serial_nbr 
  AND at.type = ad.type;
```

In other words: `seats_available` should be put into the `select` column list. As it must return just one value, you have to remove its `group by` clause as it'll probably cause problems.

If that's not what you're looking for and subquery should really be part of the `FROM` clause, then its `count` function should have an alias (e.g. `count(cust_nbr) as cnt_cust`) and you'll probably have to join that subquery to other table(s) - otherwise you'll produce cross join.

Basically, it depends on what you really have and need. Sample data, as well as desired output might help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about logic but you are facing

```
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00936: missing expression
```

Because of the extra comma (`,`) at last column in the select list.

```
....
SELECT sf.flight_nbr, sf.flight_date, seats_available --, <-- last comma
 FROM ...
.....
```